# vTiger CRM 6.3 Unable to add new user: username grayed out

Tags: javascript, php, json, vtiger

I've been working with vTiger CRM for a small company to simplify their administration. So far everything works great. But I've stumbled upon the following issue:

For some unknown reason, I'm unable to add new users to the CRM. The username field is set to mandatory, but grayed out, as shown in the following image:

[image: Username field grayed out.]

I've tried a couple of things before asking what to do here:

- Made sure there are Roles, Profiles and Groups set.
- Searched around the CRM's database if I could find what exactly set the field to disabled with `SELECT * FROM vtiger_field WHERE uitype = 4`, but it only returned fields that are supposed to be disabled. Not the username one.
- Searched Google if anyone else experienced the same issue. No results.
- Checked if I could edit the fields through the Studio. However, fields for users can't be edited.

After inspecting the element, I figured it was set to `readonly=""`. However, searching any template file in `layouts/vlayout/modules/Users/*.tpl` revealed nothing. So I think some php, or json in combination with javascript is changing this. The full code of the element is:

```
<input id="Users_editView_fieldName_user_name" class="input-large " data-validation-engine="validate[required,funcCall[Vtiger_Base_Validator_Js.invokeValidation]]" name="user_name" value="" readonly="" data-fieldinfo="{"mandatory":true,"presence":true,"quickcreate":false,"masseditable":true,"defaultvalue":false,"type":"string","name":"user_name","label":"Gebruikersnaam"}" type="text">
```

So right now I'm a bit at a loss on how to fix this issue. Does anyone have experience with this or knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the username field's `uitype` is set to `106`. After diving around in vTigers code, I figured one of my modules bugged this out inside `modules/Users/models/View.php`:

```
/**
 * Function to check whether the current field is read-only
 * @return <Boolean> - true/false
 */
public function isReadOnly() {
    $currentUserModel = Users_Record_Model::getCurrentUserModel();
    if(($currentUserModel->isAdminUser() == false && $this->get('uitype') == 98) || $this->get('uitype') == 106 || $this->get('uitype') == 156 || $this->get('uitype') == 115) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it disables fields with `uitype = 106`: `$this->get('uitype') == 106`. The solution was to simply remove that condition from the if statement.